# php5 on apache, why is libmod and php5 required?

Tags: php, apache

The most common instructions to installing php5 and apache is the following:
    sudo apt-get install php5
    sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
    sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

However, you can just install apache and libapach2 mod and run php5. So why do you need the php5 package if the libapach mod package runs it just fine??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `php5` package is a *metapackage* whose job is solely to ensure that one of a number of different ways of running PHP for websites is installed. In actual use it's completely unnecessary; it's a convenience for people who just want PHP5. Type `sudo apt-get install php5` on a system without PHP5 at all, and it'll prompt you with the options available.